# Error on remote server only: "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting the following error when running the production build of my Next.js website on a remote server. It's happening on all pages that are protected by middleware. The request is to `<pagename>.json`. When running locally in the same way using:

```
next build && next start
```

Then the same requests are all OK (200 response).

Here is the log from the server:

```
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM  Error [TypeError]: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5724:19)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5881:49)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6094:35)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6510:49)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at <unknown> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:11635:30)
Nov 2 01:05:16 PM      at requireFn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:7079)
```

I'm using React 18.2.0 and Next 13.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself, turns out its an issue with the node version your working with

found an answer here https://github.com/redwoodjs/redwood/issues/6338

TLDR;

Upgrade to Node version 16*

This post below states that it should work with 16.4.0 or 16.8.0, I'm using 16.17.0 and it also works https://community.redwoodjs.com/t/moved-to-issue-tutorial-problem-typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor-or-null/3941

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving my app to Vercel, which makes me believe this was an issue with the infrastructure rather than a code problem.